# How do I Join Two MySQL Tables Using a Function

Tags: mysql, select, join

I need some help joining two table. I've got:

`my_type_table`, which has columns:

- type (VARCHAR)
- latitude (decimal)
- longitude (decimal)

...and `neighborhood_shapes`, which has columns:

- neighborhoods (VARCHAR)
- neighborhood_polygons (geometry)

I've got a function called `myWithin` which checks the latitude and longitude to see whether they are in the neighborhood polygon. It takes the lat long and the neighborhood shape as parameters. The `myWithin` function returns 0 if the point is not in the polygon and 1 if it is within the polygon.

I can make a select statement as follows:

```
SELECT type, latitude, longitude, 'Newport' AS neighborhood
  FROM my_type_table
WHERE myWithin(POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , 
               (SELECT neighborhood_shapes.neighborhood_polygons
                  FROM neighborhood_shapes
                 WHERE neighborhood_shapes.neighborhoods = 'Newport')) = 1
```

The results of this select are for example:

```
type  |  latitude | longitude | neighborhood
---------------------------------------------
small |  30.3030  | -70.7070  | Newport
```

My problem is that I have a lot of neighborhoods. I don't want to have to input the neighborhood each time. Is there a way to remove "Newport"? Basically, I want the function to run on each point and give me the type, latitude, longitude, and which neighborhood the point is in?

I could copy the above select and join the select statements with UNION ALL, but it would be a nightmare typing in each neighborhood's name. There's got to be a better way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i didnt test this of course... but it seems like it could be restructured similar to this:

```
SELECT t.type, t.latitude, t.longitude, s.neighborhood 
  FROM my_type_table t, neighborhood_shapes s
WHERE myWithin(POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', t.latitude, ' ', t.longitude, ')' ) ) ,               s.neighborhood_shapes.neighborhood_polygons ) = 1
```

Comment: Hi Randy, 

Thank you so much for the help!! Man was that fast, too! It works great. 

(Randy didn't test it so, for those who need to replicate it, here are a few very minor changes required): 

a) I had to change s.neighborhood to s.neighborhoods

b) change s.neighborhood_shapes.neighborhood_polygons to s.neighborhood_polygons

c) add another ) after s.neighborhood_polygons

I've been working on this problem for a couple of days and you solved it in 5 minutes. Again, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried...

```
SELECT DISTINCT type,
                latitude,
                longitude,
                ns.neighborhoods AS neighborhood
    FROM my_type_table,
         neighborhood_shapes ns
    WHERE myWithin(POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , 
                   (SELECT neighborhood_shapes.neighborhood_polygons
                        FROM  neighborhood_shapes
                        WHERE neighborhood_shapes.neighborhoods = ns.neighborhoods)) = 1
```

Comment: (I haven't checked this as I have nothing like your function available to me.)

Comment: seems like a similar response - sorry yours was not visible at the time of my posting...

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNeighborhood ($neighborhood) {


$sql = "SELECT type, latitude, longitude, 'Newport' AS neighborhood
  FROM my_type_table
WHERE myWithin(POINTFROMTEXT( CONCAT( 'POINT(', latitude, ' ', longitude, ')' ) ) , 
               (SELECT neighborhood_shapes.neighborhood_polygons
                  FROM neighborhood_shapes
                 WHERE neighborhood_shapes.neighborhoods = $neighborhood)) = 1";

$result = /**  Do Query Here**/

return $result;
}
```